# How to implement Git projects in Talend?

Tags: git, talend

We have a remote machine which has Talend studio installed. 2 users are accessing this remote machine via different logins.  Also, two different logins to connect to Talend studio, but using same branch(TestTalendProject/Development).  Both of these users see same jobs,etc... in the Talend Studio.  How to implement that they both see there own jobs, then they publish to the same workspace(TestTalendProject).

Answer (score 3):

You can synchronize a project by using git for windows.

- create an empty project  my_project  on gitlab / github.
- create a project MY_PROJECT on Talend
- do a git clone of my_project in Talend/workspace/MY_PROJECT

Add .gitignore file with :

```
**/jobInfo.properties
.JETEmitters/
.Java/
.metadata/
code/routines/system/*.*
temp/
sqlPatterns/
.settings
poms/
#talend.project
#.project
```

- add your first Job

then

```
git add .
git commit -m 'feat(xxx): WIP my first job'
git push
```

..and that's all, TADA !

Hope it's help :) !

David

Answer (score 1):

You don't state whether you have the subscription or the open version of Talend Studio, but as the subscription version has Git already integrated I'll assume you're using Talend Open Studio.

As the files that Talend uses to keep track of its jobs/routes etc. are XML based, you can simply use a regular centralised Git flow:

- Create a remote repository
- User 1 commits their local changes and pushes to remote branch
- User 2 pulls from remote branch to their local branch, resolves conflicts (if any), commits and pushes to the remote branch
- repeat as required

As long as the workflow is agreed by each developer, there shouldn't be too much need for conflict resolution and any user-specific files can be added to .gitignore to avoid tracking their changes.